# Why is the fetch request time and request time displayed in the Chrome Network Timing tab different?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to understand why the total fetch request time logged by my application is different than the time displayed in the Chrome Dev Tools "Network > Timing" tab.

Consider this example that logs the difference between the fetch start time & the time of the fetch response:

```js
const startTime = new Date();
fetch('https://somedomain.com/api/route')
  .then(res => {
    const completeTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(completeTime - startTime)
  })
```

Now, when I check Chrome's "Network" tab, click on the request in the list and then click on the "Timing" tab- I am presented with a breakdown of the different phases of the request with the total time listed at the bottom. This time is always less than the time logged from example above. Normally the difference is 1-10ms but I have observed differences as high as a several hundred milliseconds.

What factors influence this difference?

Comment: Why would you expect your time logging to be less than the network time? The fetch needs a response in order to go to the then(). If it times out it would go to catch instead

Comment: @charlietfl - I would not expect the logged time to be less, I would expect it be the same or very close.

I am wondering what factors would cause a difference of several hundred milliseconds. Example: If the Network tab reports the request time as 40ms what would explain my logged time being 600ms?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to monitor the fetch requests via JS is pretty much pointless.
I will explain why:

**first** of all, you are several layers "above" chrome. You are wasting time instantiating a new date object, retrieving its timestamp, generating a fetch request which is a promise that JS inserts into the event loop, and many more overheads due to JS JIT compilation process. this can explain several extra milliseconds (I would guess less than 100).

**second**, the promise was inserted into the event loop queue and will be handled only after the queue that was running during the response from the server ended. Meaning that even after an HTTP response was received, the current queue might be taking a while to finish (for example if you were in the middle of some math calculations). this can account for several dozens of extra milliseconds (I would guess up to several hundreds).

**third** and most important is Chrome's maximum parallel connections per domain, which is default to 6. This means that if your page was in the process of sending more than 6 HTTP requests, some of them just aren't fired until those before them have finished. I made a test where I tried to fetch 9 different things, and the extra milliseconds for the first requests were ~200ms but the extra milliseconds for the 7th-9th requests were a whopping ~1500ms!

I hope I didn't miss anything else that might affect the inaccuracy of JS in this matter.
Cheers!